# AngularJS array split

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am relatively new to AngularJS. I am getting my data from java spring through `$http.get` request in the following format:

```
[
  {
    "obj1": 1039751,
    "obj2": "ABC",
    "obj3": "INDIA",
    "obj4": 57,
    "obj5": 16,
    "obj6": 43
  },
  {
    "obj1": 895321,
    "obj2": "PQR",
    "obj3": "AUSTRALIA",
    "obj4": 86,
    "obj5": 43,
    "obj6": 24
  },
  {
    "obj1": 926384,
    "obj2": "MNO",
    "obj3": "DUBAI",
    "obj4": 16,
    "obj5": 12,
    "obj6": 76
  },
  {
    "obj1": 837537,
    "obj2": "LMN",
    "obj3": "ENGLAND",
    "obj4": 83,
    "obj5": 15,
    "obj6": 43
  },
  {
    "obj1": 867152,
    "obj2": "JKL",
    "obj3": "JAPAN",
    "obj4": 49,
    "obj5": 76,
    "obj6": 16
  },
  {
    "obj1": 1003783,
    "obj2": "XYZ",
    "obj3": "BHUTAN",
    "obj4": 16,
    "obj5": 42,
    "obj6": 94
  },
  {
    "obj1": 864287,
    "obj2": "DEF",
    "obj3": "USA",
    "obj4": 96,
    "obj5": 16,
    "obj6": 37
  }
]
```

---

My app.js:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ['smart-table']);
app.controller("ctrl", function($scope, $rootScope, $timeout, $http) {
    init();

    function init() {
        $scope.rowCollection = {};
        $scope.isGlobalVisible = {};

        $http.get('rest/obz/getAllObjects').success(function(obdata) {
            console.log(obdata);
            $scope.rowCollection = obdata;
            console.log(rowCollection);
        }).error(function() {
            console.log("Error");
        });
    }
});
```

I want to split the above array as separate arrays of obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4, obj5 and obj6 in AngularJS.as

```
obj1 = [{1039751,895321,926384,837537,867152,1003783,864287}]

obj2 = [{"ABC","PQR","MNO","LMN","JKL","XYZ","DEF"}]
```

and so on.

How to split them separably in js?

Comment: I don't think this an Angular problem so much as it is a JavaScript one.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried angular.forEach and push the values on the new objects?

Something like

```
$http.get('rest/obz/getAllObjects')
.success(function(obdata){
  console.log(obdata);
  $scope.rowCollection = obdata;
  console.log(rowCollection);

  angular.forEach($scope.rowCollection, function(value, key) {
    if (this[key] == undefined) {
      this[key] = [];
    };
    this[key].push(value);
  });
}).error(function(){
  console.log("Error");
});
```